# Cross join addition with 2D lists

Tags: python

I created a post earlier regarding cross joining two lists with addition. However, suppose I have two lists that are two dimensional.

For Example:

```
list1 = ([5,2,8],[1,2,3])
list2 = ([11,6,3],[3,2,1])
sum_list = []
```

My expected output would be:

```
print (sum_list)

Output:
[16,11,8],[8,7,6],
[13,8,5], [5,4,3],
[19,14,11],[11,10,9],
[12,7,4],[4,3,2],
[13,8,5],[5,4,3],
[14,9,6],[6,5,4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly do not know why you would do this, but heres the code:

```
list1 = ([5,2,8],[1,2,3])
list2 = ([11,6,3],[3,2,1])
sum_list = []

for i in list1:
  for j in i:
    for k in list2:
      templ=[]
      for l in k:
        templ.append(j+l)
      sum_list.append(templ)

print(sum_list)
```